# What type of connector should I use for multichannel(16) RF analog signals? Can I use HDMI?

Tags: connector, hdmi

I need to select a connector type for 16 pair of wire. The signal is analogic and in the frequency range of 1 MHz. I prefer not to use 16 SMA connectors, however I am fine to use 4 blocks of connector or less. The connectors would be preferably shielded.

Comment: impedance? crosstalk?  ribbon cable with interleaved gnd?

Comment: balanced or unbalanced?

Comment: Impedance : 50 ohms, 
Unbalanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a shielded Ethernet cable:

[image]

This gives 4 shielded pairs, so just ground the white wire. You need 16 connections, so get 4 Ethernet cables. Voilla.

---

### EDIT

[This appears to be more of what you need.](http://www.bhuwalinsu.com/insulated-cables-shielded-cables.html)
[image]

---

If I were you I would seriously just get some aluminum foil and wrap it around small cables and then put a heat shrink tube around the whole thing. (And ground the aluminum foils)